# Swift.. SKSpriteNode having jerky movements when kept idle for some time

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm working on a Bow&Arrow-BalloonShoot game where balloon nodes appears on screen from bottom and floats upward and disappears when reaches top of screen. It works fine if you are playing with it. But if I keep it idle for 10 - 15 minutes, it starts having jerky movements while floating to top. Also if I shoot arrow, arrow is also jerking. I can't find why this is happening.
Does anyone know why this happens and how to get rid of this.

Comment: Please add some code so that people can identify the issue.

Comment: Use Instruments to find leaks, and add information about memory usage to your current question. Also, what draws count says (`view.showsDrawCount = true`)?

Comment: This sounds like there are too many nodes being created (perhaps on top of each other), or you have some runaway code in one of your methods that are called every frame (like `update`). Or as WW said, you have a memory leak of some sort. look to see how many nodes are on screen.. if you have a ton of new nodes after 15 seconds that shouldn't be there, then that is your problem.

Comment: Yeah.. There was issue of too many node were created and were not getting removed. As I removed the balloon nodes which are out of screen my issue got resolved. Thanks to @Whirlwind and  Fluidity.